# C++11 template function to accept multiple template alias

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to create a template function which accepts multiple template alias.
Here is a simple example to make more sense.

There are template aliases **TAlias1 and TAlias2**

```
template <typename T>
using TAlias1 = TClass1<T, 2>;

template <typename T>
using TAlias2 = TClass2<T, 3>;
```

...then I'd like to create a template function accepting any of the aliases above:

```
template <typename T, template<typename> class TClass>
TClass<T> someOperation(const TClass<T> &a, const TClass<T> &b)
{
   ...
}

int main()
{
   TAlias1<float> a;
   TAlias1<float> b;

   TAlias1<float> c = someOperation(a,b);

   return 0;
}
```

However it results in compilation error in Visual Studio 2013:

Is there any solution for such cases?

**EDIT:**

Here is a full example which produces the error:

```
template <typename T, int I>
struct TClass1 {};

template <typename T, int I>
struct TClass2 {};

template <typename T>
using TAlias1 = TClass1<T, 2>;

template <typename T>
using TAlias2 = TClass2<T, 3>;

// this should accept TAlias1 and TAlias2
template <typename T, template<typename> class TClass>
TClass<T> someOperation(const TClass<T> &a, const TClass<T> &b) { return {}; }

int main()
{
    TAlias1<float> a;
    TAlias1<float> b;
    TAlias1<float> c = someOperation(a,b);

    TAlias2<float> d;
    TAlias2<float> e;
    TAlias2<float> f = someOperation(d,e);

   return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error C2784: 'TClass<T> someOperation(const TClass<T> &,const TClass<T> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const TClass<T> &' from 'TClass1<float,2>'
```

Comment: The above code will not generate that error, because among other things you did not cause template type deduction to occcur, because you did not actually call `testFunction`.  Please include a http://sscce.org -- a minimal example that generates the actual error you see.  As an aside, `mynamespace::` is also probably not needed, remove elements until the error no longer occurs, and then back up 1 step and post that.

Comment: The question is now updated with a full example.

Comment: The question is now updated with a bunch of code that was not relevant to your error deleted.  The goal isn't to add more code for more code's sake: it is to add code sufficient so that the error is generated, and eliminate code that is not required to generate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the 2nd template argument for the `someOperation` function. The template alias doesn't introduce new types, and it works like a typedef. That means, that even that `TAlias1` accepts only one template argument, it is still a template with 2 argument (where the 2nd argument is set).

And indeed, if you change the function to this :

```
template <typename T, template<typename,int> class TClass>
TClass<T,2> someOperation(const TClass<T,2> &a, const TClass<T,2> &b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

it will compile (of course, you need to make `operator+` const method).

A better approach would be not to use template class as the 2nd template argument, and change the function to something like this :

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto someOperation(const T1 &a, const T2 &b) -> decltype(a+b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

or maybe even :

```
template <typename T>
T someOperation(const T &a, const T &b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
template <typename T, template<typename> class TClass>
TClass<T> someOperation(const TClass<T> &a, const TClass<T> &b)
```

How would the compiler resolve the `I` parameter if it is not provided by any means?  What you need to do is this:

```
template <typename T, int I>
TClass<T, I> someOperation(const TClass<T, I> &a, const TClass<T, I> &b)
```

This function will work for every `TClass` concretization. Here is your full **working** example:

```
template <typename T, int I>
struct TClass
{
public:
    T value;

    TClass<T,I> operator+(const TClass<T,I> &b) const
    {  
       TClass<T, I> result;
       result.value = value + b.value;
       return result;
    }

    int getI()
    {
        return I;
    }
};

template <typename T>
using TAlias1 = TClass<T, 2>;

template <typename T>
using TAlias2 = TClass<T, 3>;

// this should accept TAlias1 and TAlias2
template <typename T, int I>
TClass<T, I> someOperation(const TClass<T, I> &a, const TClass<T, I> &b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    TAlias1<float> a;
    TAlias1<float> b;
    TAlias1<float> c = someOperation(a,b);

   return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit**    After OP's comment. An alias is just an alias, not a different class. The function will accept all `TClass` objects. You can restrict it only by making partially specialized functions for each alias:

```
template<typename T>
TAlias1<T> foo(TAlias1<T> a, TAlias1<T> b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want cannot be done.

This should work:

```
TAlias1<float> c = someOperation<float, TAlias1>(a,b);
```

But the automatic template deduction fails, because `a` and `b` are actually of type `TClass<float,2>`, and that does not match the expected template parameter.

Yes, they are declared as `TAlias1<float` that does match the expected template parameter, but the alias is just that, an alias, it is not the real type of the variable, and it is not used for template deduction.

You can try a few workarounds, for example:

```
template <typename T>
struct TAlias1 : TClass<T, 2> {};
```

But you may have a few typecheck problems here and there...

And of course, you can override the template function with both the `TClass` arguments. Actually I'm not sure why you don't do that in the first place...